# Query the join Table of HABTM related Models

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

Im working with CakePHP since very recently..

I've got a table 'advertisers' and a table 'users', aswell as a table 'advertisers_users', that only contains 'advertiser_id' and 'user_id'.
. User hasAndBelongsToMany Advertiser.

I need an array in which i can find all advertisers (names and id's) that habtm to the current user id in my User-Controller. how can i do that in cakephp?

like

```
$this->User->Advertiser->find('all', array('conditions' => '?'));
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Most of the time I've found the easiest way is to query your bridging table: `$this->AdvertiserUser->find('all');`

Comment: where would you write this function down? doesnt work if i write $au = $this->User->AdvertiserUser->find('all'); in my UsersController.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->User->find(user_id);
```

Give an array with (if $this->User->recursive is set to 1 )

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2745
            [name] => Chocolate Frosted Sugar Bombs
        )
    [Advertiser] => Array
        (
           [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 123
                    [name] => blabla
                )
           [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 124
                    [name] => blabla
                )
           [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 125
                    [name] => blabla
                )
        )
)
```